# app engine simple java webservice

Tags: java, web-services, google-app-engine

I like to expose one **JAVA** method as a **Web service** that will accept `POST` ,strip the parameters out of it and reply accordingly. I read I have to use `doPost(req,resp)` , but How can I get to the servlet code? what should be in `web.xml`? there will not be a welcome-file ? After mapping the servlet, can I read it without the need for a `index.html` as start point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create the `doPost(req,resp)` method in your servlet and map it to a url in `web.xml`

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>HelloPost</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>packageName.HelloPost</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>HelloPost</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/post-url</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

then you can post your request to `/post-url` .You don't need to use index.html.Any url can be put in welcome file to load for the url `/`
To set `/post-url` as landing page , use

```
<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/post-url</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

you can get started here https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/creating

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know how to set the `web.xml` to start the servlet then may be [this](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-servlets/web-xml.html) will help you.